# Round number with lots of decimal places in Javascript

Tags: javascript, math

I have a number with an extreme amount of decimal places.

`1.5583255870000002e+36`

I'm struggling to find a good way to round this down to 2 decimal places using JavaScript.

I've tried a few variations using `parseFloat()` `Math.round()` and `.toFixed()`.

Here is an example using `.toPrecision()`.

```
App.currentUSDBalance = Number((App.currentBalance * App.maticPrice).toPrecision(2));
```

The result is `1.6e+36`. I was hoping for something like `1.59`.

Thanks,

Comment: "*I've tried a few variations*" OK, why not *show* us those attempts as [mre]s and explain *why* they don't meet your requirements? Otherwise, you're probably going to get a lot of suggestions that are duplicative of your previous attempts. Please familiarize yourself with [ask].

Comment: The number `1.5583255870000002e+36` doesn't actually contain any decimals, and JS doesn't have a concept of numbers with trailing zeros. What you're after is precision, not rounding, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toPrecision

Comment: Apologies for not providing more examples. I've updated my question with one.

Comment: If you need a precision of 3, then why you're setting precision of 2?

Comment: Good catch @Teemu. Unfortunately I still have a trailing `e+36` at the end. Is there an easy way to drop that?

Answer (score 2):

The following snippet should be the answer to your updated question:

```js
const yourNumber=1.234567890123e36, ndigits=3;

// returns two variations of the solution:
function mySigDig(num,dig){
 return [+(num/(10**Math.floor(Math.log10(num)))).toPrecision(dig),
 +num.toPrecision(dig).replace(/e.*/,"")]
}


console.log(mySigDig(23,ndigits));
console.log(mySigDig(2345678,ndigits));
console.log(mySigDig(yourNumber,ndigits));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately it wasn't exactly what I was looking for. I've updated my question with the results when I try `.toPrecision()`.

Comment: Changed my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for the terrible question.

I ended up solving this by converting to string and dropping the `e+X`.

```
App.currentUSDBalance = Number((App.currentBalance * App.maticPrice).toPrecision(3)).toString().split('e')[0];
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You can leave out `Number(...).toString()` as `.toPrecision(n)` returns a string anyway!

Comment: Even better. Thanks @CarstenMassmann!